# c++ program that returns half of an object

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and learning it. I am writing a simple program that returns half of an object. My code looks something like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
double half(int x)
{
  double h = x / 2;
  return h;
}

class TuitionBill
{
   friend ostream& operator+(ostream, TuitionBill);
   private:
      string student;
      double amount;
   public:
      TuitionBill(string, double);
      double operator/(int);
};

TuitionBill::TuitionBill(string student, double amt)
{
   student = student;
   amount = amt;
}

double TuitionBill::operator+(int factor)
{
   double half = amount / factor;
   return half;
}

ostream& operator+(ostream& o, TuitionBill& t)
{
   o << t.student << "  Tuition: $" << t.amount << endl;
   return o;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 47;
   double b = 39.25;
   TuitionBill tb("Smith", 4000.00);
   cout << "Half of " << a << " is " << half(a) << endl;
   cout << "Half of " << b << " is " << half(b) << endl;
   cout << "Half of " << tb << " is " << half(tb) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

What is wrong in here? I want to learn this program. Can anyone guide me through this ? I want to use template function here.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is wrong"? What is not working for you? What result did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: Your function template (not "template function") never uses the type `T`. Why is it a template? (If you're new to C++, implementing templates is not a good place to start. Start with chapter one of [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).)

Comment: Typos: you wrote `operator+` instead of `operator/`, and also `operator+` instead of `operator<<`.

Comment: And in your constructor, you're assigning the arguments to themselves. Read about member initialization in a good C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes in your code. Many of them look like typos, but the serious errors are

Not using the template parameter `T` in your function signature. This is the reason `half(tb)` did not compile since your version of `half` always expected an `int`.

Not understanding that in your constructor `student = student;` is just assigning a variable to itself. You can ensure that the class variable gets assignied by prefixing `this->` to the name of the class variable (or you can just ensure that the class variable and parameter names are different as with `ammount` and `amt`.

You might also check out the difference between assignment (what you are doing in your constructor) and initialisation (what you should be doing in your constructor).

Below is a working version of your code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
double half(T x)
{
    double h = x / 2;
    return h;
}

class TuitionBill
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const TuitionBill&);
private:
    string student;
    double amount;
public:
    TuitionBill(string, double);
    double operator/(int);
};

TuitionBill::TuitionBill(string student, double amt)
{
    this->student = student;
    amount = amt;
}

double TuitionBill::operator/(int factor)
{
    double half = amount / factor;
    return half;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const TuitionBill& t)
{
    o << t.student << "  Tuition: $" << t.amount;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 47;
    double b = 39.25;
    TuitionBill tb("Smith", 4000.00);
    cout << "Half of " << a << " is " << half(a) << endl;
    cout << "Half of " << b << " is " << half(b) << endl;
    cout << "Half of " << tb << " is " << half(tb) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```